# Creating a copy of data across 12 workbooks into one master Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Currently I've got 12 users using different workbooks to collate data.

I want to be able to have each user's data auto-update to a mastersheet in another workbook.

I've tried creating 12 connections to each workbook and then importing the data into a table but this locks the user's workbooks until the master workbook is closed.

Can someone point me in the right direction, should I be using VBA or PowerQuery? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried to use VBA? open workbooks inside a loop and get its data?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing Power Query is designed for and I would strongly advise against using VBA for it. With Power Query you can select a folder and automatically connect to all of the workbooks at once and compile their data into a single table. It doesn't require any coding and can be setup entirely from a menu interface. Just look for more recently written guides, as this process was made much easier in the last couple years as opposed to when Power Query was first released in 2014.

Comment: @Wedge thanks so much! Got it all working via Power Query really easily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wedge thanks so much. I used Power Query and got it working really well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim wbCnt As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim Folder As String
Dim SorceFile As String
Dim FileFlag As Integer

Set MySheet = ActiveSheet
'..... set your files path in local or remote system
'..... You can use array
Folder = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"
SorceFile = Dir(Folder)
While SorceFile <> ""
    If Right(sourcefile, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(sourcefile, 4) = ".xls" Then
        FileFlag = GetFileIndex(sourcefile)
        If FileFlag = -1 Then
            Set wbCnt = Workbooks.Open(SorceFile)
        Else
            wbCnt = Workbooks(FileFlag)
        enif

        '..... select your sheet .......
        Set DataSheet = wbCnt.Sheets(1)
        '.... Copy data from source to your master sheet

        If FileFlag = -1 Then
            wbCnt.Close
        End If
    End If
    SorceFile = Dir
Wend
End Sub

Function GetFileIndex(ByVal FileName As String) As Integer
Dim FileNum As Integer, ErrNum As Integer
Dim Cnt As Integer
On Error Resume Next
FileNum = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #FileNum
Close FileNum
ErrNum = Err
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case ErrNum
    Case 0
        '.... File is not open
        GetFileIndex = -1
    Case 70
        For Cnt = 1 To Workbooks.Count
            If Workbooks(Cnt).Name = FileName Then
                GetFileIndex = Cnt
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Case Else
        Error ErrNum
End Select
End Function
```